# Calling An Array That Was Created in An Iteration

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader, filereader

so I'm writing a program that will read a csv file and put each individual line of the file into an array. I would like to know if it would be possible to name a singular array that was created in the while loop. I would also love to know if you have any ideas on how I'd be able to separate the lines (containing the rows of the csv file) by the columns of the csv file.

This is my code:

```
package sample.package;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SampleClass {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static String fileLocation;                                                  //Used to declare the file path

public static void readAndArray(String fileLocation) throws IOException {           //Method to read a file and put each line into an array
    BufferedReader lineRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation));     //Read the file and be able to parse it into separate lines

        String line = lineRead.readLine();                                          //Put line into variable so it isn't a boolean statement

        while ((line = lineRead.readLine()) !=null) {                               //Make it possible to print out array as BufferedReader is used

            String[] oneLine = new String[] {line};                                 //Put parsed line in new array and parsing that data for individual spots in array
            System.out.println(oneLine[0]);                                         //Print out each oneLine array
        }
        lineRead.close();                                                           //Neatly close BufferedReader and FileReader
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    readAndArray("filePath"); //Initialize method by inputting the file path


    }
}
```

Thanks so much guys!

Comment: I think the code does not do what you expect it to do. You may want to revisit the basics, e.g. [through this Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html).

Comment: I believe the program does operate the way I'd like it to, but why do you think it does not?

Comment: With all respect, have you considered taking a programming class?

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I have, in fact, taken 3 classes. What do you suggest I improve on?

Comment: `String[] oneLine = new String[] {line}; System.out.println(oneLine[0]);` could be simplified to `System.out.println(line);`. What you probably want is an array with `length` = number of lines, and one line per array-entry.

Comment: Please consider using Apache Commons CSV: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Comment: @AlexTaylor8 Thank you so much for the suggestion, this will help a lot! I was shown how to use the BufferedReader and FileReader, but your idea would be much cleaner and easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of: Welcome to stackoverflow!

I assume that your question relates to some sort of educational programming task, if not: There are a number of libraries dealing with CSV files (with additional features like reading header rows and read row entries by header/column name, etc).

***But ... why should it be a complicated task to write a CSV parser, i mean, its basically just values separated by commas, phhh!?***

To cut a long story short: There is [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), but don't expect that all your `.csv` files stick to it. Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values):

> The CSV file format is not fully standardized. The basic idea of
> separating fields with a comma is clear, but that idea gets
> complicated when the field data may also contain commas or even
> embedded line-breaks. CSV implementations may not handle such field
> data, or they may use quotation marks to surround the field. Quotation
> does not solve everything: some fields may need embedded quotation
> marks, so a CSV implementation may include escape characters or escape
> sequences.

After you are aware of and hopefully understand the provided warning about compatibility the following code example completely ignores it and provides a quick and dirty solution (don't use it in production, seriously ... how to not be fired 101: use a well tested library like [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) or [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Path path = Paths.get("some path"); // TODO Change to path to an CSV file

    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path))
    {
        List<List<String>> rows = lines
                // Map each line of the file to its fields (String[])
                .map(line -> line.split(","))
                // Map the fields of each line to unmodifiable lists
                .map(fields -> Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(fields))
                // Collect the unmodifiable lists in an unmodiable list (listception)
                .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());

        // Ensure file is not empty.
        if (rows.isEmpty())
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("empty file");
        }

        // Ensure all lines have the same number of fields.
        int fieldsPerRow = rows.get(0).size();
        if (!rows.stream().allMatch(row -> row.size() == fieldsPerRow))
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("not all rows have the same number of fields");
        }

        // Assume the file has a header line appearing as the first line.
        System.out.printf("Column names: %s\n", rows.get(0));

        // Read the data rows.
        rows.stream()
                .skip(1) // Skip header line
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    catch (IOException | UncheckedIOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace(); // TODO Handle exception
    }
}
```

This code assumes:

- Fields are separated by commas
- A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed (behaviour of BufferedReader used by `Files.lines()`)
- All lines have the same number of fields
- The first line is a header line
- The implementor was too lazy to mind fields enclosed in double quotes

Quick and dirty ... and violates the RFC ;)